# Multiple session cookies created for the same Laravel app

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, session, cookies

I have a Laravel 5.2 app laying on a domain like this: `https://www.example.com`.

The `laravel_session` cookie is configured to use the dot notation (to include subdomains):

**config/session.php:**

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN', null)
```

**.env** file on the server:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=.example.com
```

I'm using the **database** as the session driver.

Now, there are cases when the session cookie gets duplicated, and in the cookie list I can see entries like these:

- `laravel_session`, domain: `.example.com`
- `laravel_session`, domain: `.www.example.com`

The same thing happens with the Facebook session cookies, when a user used Facebook to authenticate:

- `fbm_123456`, domain: `.example.com`
- `fbm_123456`, domain: `.www.example.com`

In both cases, the expiry dates on the duplicated cookies are different

**This cookie duplication causes problems with authentication** - some users try to log in, but get redirected back to the homepage, with the auth state unchanged.

I can't seem to reproduce the issue, or rather what's causing it. I think, though, it may be linked to Laravel session expiring, or to logging the user in via the remember-me token.

Does anyone have an idea why would the cookies be duplicated?

**UPDATE:**

Actually, I realize now that the only difference between our other Laravel project and this one is that here we explicitly set the `laravel_session` domain (to `.example.com`). May be a lead.

Comment: Is you website accessible by both domains example.com and www.example.com?

Comment: Nope, we have redirects in place: from anything to `https://www`

Answer (score 2):

To anyone having a similar problem: we solved it actually easily after we realized we could specify the session cookie name ourselves, per (sub)domain.

So, we adjusted the **config/session.php** `cookie` key:

```
'cookie' => env('SESSION_COOKIE_NAME', 'laravel_session')
```

and then we set the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` variable in respective **.env** files, like this:

```
# subdomainA.example.com
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME=subdomainA_session
```

or

```
# subdomainB.example.com
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME=subdomainB_session
```

etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We regenerated the session after login and the problem was solved.

```
session()->regenerate();
```